# How to test view mixins in Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, unit-testing, integration-testing, django-rest-framework

In my Django site I use Django REST framework. To not repeat myself, I created a couple mixins to simplify writing my view sets (here is an [example of a similar style of mixin](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/blob/master/rest_framework_bulk/mixins.py#L11)).

My question is how do I go about testing such a mixin? If it was a regular view exposed on some URL, I would use `APITestCase` provided by the framework, but since my mixin is not a standalone object and needs to be inherited from to be actually useful, this way of testing is not applicable.

Is there some way to mock the rest of the view? Or do I have to create a dummy application using this mixin and do integration tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test Django REST Framework view mixins the same way that you should test standard Django view mixins. You test it when attached to a view or you mock up all of the parts of a standard view that it would rely on.

You should be able to test mixins when attached to views in the same way that you would test standard views, because mixins should behave consistently in ways that are testable. You may need to create test views for each case that the mixin works with, which is what we had to do with [DRF JSON API](https://github.com/kevin-brown/drf-json-api) when creating the tests.

In the case of Django REST Framework Bulk, the best way would probably be to create a view that has the mixins attached to it, and test that it responds as expected. For the bulk mixins, lets assume that the following needs to be tested:

- Single object POST still works
- Multiple object POST on the list
- Multiple object PUT on the list
- Multiple object PATCH on the list
- Multiple object DELETE on the list

This would require *at least* five tests, most likely split up for what they are testing. You would also need to make sure that the tests cover the hooks that are also being called, as well as any side effects that are expected.

The Python [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) module helps a lot with mocking views (if you want to do that) and allows you to determine if methods (such as the hooks) are called.